# PDO Statement Not Setting Values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to run a PDO update statement, but none of the fields are being updated. Here is my PDO query. I've gone through and tried to find where the values were being changed and found that where being assigned nothing. I found the problem right when the values are escaped (You'll see my comment placed there). I know it probably something I'm overlooking but I haven't been able to figure out yet.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name'];}else{ $name = '';}
    if(isset($_POST['city'])){ $city = $_POST['city'];}else{ $city = '';}
    if(isset($_POST['state'])){ $state = $_POST['state'];}else{ $state = '';}
    if(isset($_POST['address_line1'])){ $address_line1 = $_POST['address_line1'];}else{ $address_line1 = '';}
    if(isset($_POST['address_line2'])){ $address_line2 = $_POST['address_line2'];}else{ $address_line2 = '';}
    if(isset($_POST['city'])){ $city = $_POST['city'];}else{ $city = '';}
    if(isset($_POST['state'])){ $state = $_POST['state'];}else{ $state = '';}
    if(isset($_POST['zip_code'])){ $zip_code = $_POST['zip_code'];}else{ $zip_code = '';}
    if(isset($_POST['last_modified_by'])){ $last_modified_by = $_POST['last_modified_by'];}else{ $last_modified_by = 'admin';}
    $last_modified_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $confirmcode = 'y';
    if(isset($_POST['bitactive'])){ $bitactive = $_POST['bitactive'];}else{ $bitactive = '';}

    //Test portion 1 = Values are correct
    // echo $address_line1 . "<p>";
    // echo $city . "<p>";
    // echo $zip_code . "<p>";
    // exit;

    $support_broker_id = $_GET['id'];
    $user_exists = "SELECT * FROM lu_agency WHERE agency_id =". $support_broker_id;
    $statement = $conn->query($sql);
    $result = $statement->fetch();
    $count = $statement->rowCount();

    $name = $row['name'];
    $address_line1 = $row['address_line1'];
    $address_line2 = $row['address_line2'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $state = $row['state'];
    $zip_code = $row['zip_code'];
    $last_modified_by = $row['last_modified_by'];
    $last_modified_date = $row['last_modified_date'];
    $bitactive = $row['bitactive'];

    //Test portion two: Values are correct
    // echo $address_line1 . "<p>";
    // echo $city . "<p>";
    // echo $zip_code . "<p>";
    // exit;

    if($count > 0)
    {
        $sqlupdate = "UPDATE lu_agency 
                      SET name = :name,
                          address_line1 = :address_line1,
                          address_line2 = :address_line2,
                          city = :city,
                          state = :state,
                          zip_code = :zip_code,
                          last_modified_by = :last_modified_by,
                          last_modified_date = :last_modified_date,
                          bitactive = :bitactive
                      WHERE agency_id= ". $support_broker_id;

    //Here is where only $city and $support_broker_id have values, the others don't show up
    echo $address_line1 . "<p>";
    echo $city . "<p>";
    echo $zip_code . "<p>";
    echo $support_broker_id . "<p>";
    exit;

        $preparedstmt = $conn->prepare($sqlupdate);

        $preparedstmt->execute(
            array(
                ':name'=>$name,
                ':address_line1'=>$address_line1,
                ':address_line2'=>$address_line2,
                ':city'=>$city,
                ':state'=>$state,
                ':zip_code'=>$zip_code,
                ':last_modified_by'=>$last_modified_by,
                ':last_modified_date'=>$last_modified_date,
                ':bitactive'=>$bitactive
                )
        );

        header("Location: http://173.254.127.52/~avenuet7/supporttables.php?msg=1");
    }

}
```

Comment: PS you still have to use prepared statements for `SELECT` queries to avoid SQL injection. (`...WHERE agency_id = :agency_id`).

Answer (score 1):

`$row` is undefined. It should be `$result`:

```
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // you declared `$result` not `$row`
```

And why not use prepared statements all through out:

```
$user_exists = "SELECT * FROM lu_agency WHERE agency_id =". $support_broker_id; // still directly injecting?
```

Final look:

```
$support_broker_id = $_GET['id'];

$user_exists = "SELECT * FROM lu_agency WHERE agency_id = :support_broker_id ";
// not `$sql` use `$user_exists`!
$statement = $conn->prepare($user_exists);
$statement->bindParam(':support_broker_id', $support_broker_id);
$statement->execute();

$count = $statement->rowCount();

if($count > 0) {

    $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sqlupdate = "
        UPDATE lu_agency SET 
            name =                  :name,
            address_line1 =         :address_line1,
            address_line2 =         :address_line2,
            city =                  :city,
            state =                 :state,
            zip_code =              :zip_code,
            last_modified_by =      :last_modified_by,
            last_modified_date =    :last_modified_date,
            bitactive =             :bitactive

            WHERE agency_id =       :support_broker_id
    ";

    $preparedstmt = $conn->prepare($sqlupdate);

    $preparedstmt->execute(
        array(
            ':name'                 => $result['name'],
            ':address_line1'        => $result['address_line1'],
            ':address_line2'        => $result['address_line2'],
            ':city'                 => $result['city'],
            ':state'                => $result['state'],
            ':zip_code'             => $result['zip_code'],
            ':last_modified_by'     => $result['last_modified_by'],
            ':last_modified_date'   => $result['last_modified_date'],
            ':bitactive'            => $result['bitactive'],
            ':support_broker_id'    => $support_broker_id,
    ));

    header("Location: http://173.254.127.52/~avenuet7/supporttables.php?msg=1");
}
```

Sidenote: Always add this after making a connection:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Thank you that was extremely helpful, I'm in the process of updating legacy code and didn't get around to removing all of the old statements.

However, $count returns 0, even though the query should return one row.

Comment: @jkjmr6 my goodness i forgot the `execute();` execution of the first prepared statement. check my revision on that part and kindly try it again. im glad this helped

Comment: No problem! I looked over the documentation and noticed something was missing. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @jkjmr6 yeah okay, let me know if this indeed worked.

Comment: @jkjmr6 oh okay, so it means, there is no rows selected to begin with? maybe there isn't at all with that corresponding ID

Comment: Still not updating. Also watch for the extra comma before the WHERE statement in $sqlupdate and in $support_broker_id in the execute statment.

Comment: Good looking out, but $count returns 1 row that corresponds to the id.

Comment: @jkjmr6 so that means it found a row right? try to check `var_dump($result);` to check its contents. if `$count > 0` then it should execute those codes inside the if

Comment: Looking good so far. 

`array(11) { ["agency_id"]=> string(2) "49" ["name"]=> string(9) "Crystallie" ["agency_type_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["address_line1"]=> string(0) "" ["address_line2"]=> string(0) "" ["city"]=> string(7) "Fayette" ["state"]=> string(2) "MO" ["zip_code"]=> string(0) "" ["last_modified_by"]=> string(5) "admin" ["last_modified_date"]=> string(19) "2006-03-24 18:58:21" ["bitactive"]=> string(1) "0" }`

Comment: @jkjmr6 oh so its populated now, so now we know that those variables holds values, now does update work?

Comment: Nope, none of the values corresponding to ID are changed.

Comment: @jkjmr6 could it be that you are connected to the wrong db ?

Comment: @meda imo, i don't think its about the connection since the first prepare worked successfully. still using the same connection `$conn`, however can seem to replicate the problem on the update, the statement looks fine.

Comment: @meda Nope, database checks out. I'm stumped.